# Change border color and style of Active Object in Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, fabricjs

I am adding one Image on Canvas. I am using FabricJS on Frontend and Laravel on the backend.
I want to change the color and style of the control's broder.
Here is my Object in Fabric JS

```
var homeImage = new fabric.Image(homeImgElement, {
  left: -10,
  top: -10,
  angle: 0,
  width:620,
  height:500,
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check Fabric JS document for more control options.
Here you go.
You can even use property which is corderSize.

```
var homeImage = new fabric.Image(homeImgElement, {
  left: -10,
  top: -10,
  angle: 0,
  width:620,
  height:500,
  borderColor: '#000',
  cornerColor: '#DDD',
  cornerStyle:'circle',
  cornerSize:5,
});
```

Comment: Edit: Color values need to be in quotes